# Find the height of dynamically created div

Tags: javascript

Neither of the properties clientHeight and offsetHeight has worked out for me while I try to determine the height of the div created dynamically. Could someone suggest alternative please? Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: are you able to use jquery at all?? if so, then it's quite simple.

Comment: You can write a function to get the distance from your div to the nearest available element above it. Then do the same for the nearest element below it. Then get the distance between those 2 elements (the element above and below the div), then subtract the first 2 values from the last value calculated. In other words... distance between 2 elements - (height above div + height below div) should give you a really close approximation. Depending on how you write the function, you could simply do -> bottom element's distance from top - top element's distance from top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a fan of JQuery.  I use the "native" mydiv.offsetHeight - works with IE and FF.

Comment: I don't seem to get it right with Javascript though I use the correct method. Could someone help me asap please? This is very urgent. Thanks in advance.

Comment: myDiv.offsetHeight and myDiv.offsetWidth work OK.  If you use "position = 'relative';"  the width appears to pick up the screen width.  With "position = 'absolute';" the width and height reflect the real width and height.

Answer (score 2):

Ashriya,

if you are able to use jquery, (as an alternative) then you can easily find (and set) the height of any div (in your domain) as such:

```
// get the height
var myDivHeight = $('#myDiv').css('height');


// set the height
$('#myDiv').css('height', myDivHeight + someothernumber);
```

hope this helps a 'little'...

**[edit]** - forgot to use the # id placeholders in my original response. have corrected above!! - argh :)

Comment: Hello there,
It doesn't seem to work..:( Is there any other possible alternative in JavaScript itself?

Comment: ashriya =- the above example of course assumes that you have id's set on your divs. it wasn't explicitly mentioned in your OP, so obviously, will rely heavily on that discipline being followed. (plus i had omitted the # id placeholders originally. have corrected my example)- doh!!

Comment: ashriya - i'm not sure what to suggest. this certainly works under 'normal' circumstances and is something I do all the time with great success. maybe you could post the little bit of html/jquery code that you have and i could look at that.

Comment: Allright Jim, I'll tell my actual problem. I have to show a div onmouseover of an icon. It does get shown up, but in the bottom, so am unable to see the content. How do I format the div so that the div shows up right next to the icon itself? P.S. The div is actually a label created by a certain Label.js file

Comment: Label.prototype.draw = function() {
var projection = this.getProjection(); 
var position = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.get('position'));

Comment: this.span_.innerHTML = this.get('text').toString(); var projection = map.getProjection(); var bounds = map.getBounds(); var sw = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(bounds.getSouthWest()); var ne = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(bounds.getNorthEast()); var mapheight = Math.abs(ne.y - sw.y); var mapwidth = Math.abs(ne.x - sw.x); var mapvlimit = mapheight / 2; var mapHlimit = mapwidth / 2;

Comment: if (position.x > mapvlimit) { fx = position.x - 100; } else { fx = position.x + 100; }

Comment: var div = this.div_; div.style.left = fx +'px'; div.style.top = position.y + 'px';

Comment: hmm - i think this is a different question really. it might be best to redo it with that full detail as the answers given will be quite different and potentially more focussed on your dilema.

Comment: Oh no:( Its close to a month since I'm bothered with this app..Can sumone help me asap please? I gotta finish it this week. Thanks.

Comment: ashriya - i'm sure the SO community will offer as much help as they can if you provide your exact needs on this one.

Comment: Can you please provide me the link, Jim?

Comment: SO = stackoverflow!! ;) i.e. on here

Comment: Please is there nobody to help me out? Its urgent:(

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, that I completely understand your problem. However, a following approach may be helpful.

```
<html>
<body onload="documentReady();">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function documentReady() {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerText = "I'm a div, excluded from DOM!";

        var helper = div.cloneNode(true);
        helper.style.position = "relative";
        helper.style.top = "-100000px";
        helper.style.left = "-100000px";
        document.body.appendChild(helper);

        var height = helper.offsetHeight;
        var width = helper.offsetWidth;

        document.body.removeChild(helper);

        alert([height, width]);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Allright, I'll tell my actual problem. I have to show a div onmouseover of an icon. It does get shown up, but in the bottom, so am unable to see the content. How do I format the div so that the div shows up right next to the icon itself? 
P.S. The div is actually a label created by a certain Label.js file.

Comment: Label.prototype.draw = function() {var projection = this.getProjection();
var position = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.get('position'));

Comment: this.span_.innerHTML = this.get('text').toString();
var projection = map.getProjection();
var bounds = map.getBounds();
var sw = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(bounds.getSouthWest());
var ne = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(bounds.getNorthEast());
var mapheight = Math.abs(ne.y - sw.y);
var mapwidth = Math.abs(ne.x - sw.x);
var mapvlimit = mapheight / 2;
var mapHlimit = mapwidth / 2;

Comment: if (position.x > mapvlimit) {
        fx = position.x - 100;
    } 
else {
        fx = position.x + 100;
    }

Comment: var div = this.div_;
div.style.left = fx +'px';
div.style.top = position.y + 'px';

Comment: It looks like a google maps api. I'm not familar with it.

Nevertheless, if you want to make a popup, you should use an 'absolute' position to set it arround an icon and set a z-index to bring the div up to the top layer:

div.style.position = 'absolute';
div.style.zIndex = '1000'; //a big number

Also, make sure that the div has width and height, if they are undefined, you can use my snippet to get them.

Comment: Yes Jim, you're right. Its a Google maps API version 3. I've set the position of the div to absolute only(in the aspx page).

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's `outerHeight()`.

Comment: Could u provide me with the syntax please?

Comment: `$('div#whatever').outerHeight()`