# Why jquery height and javascript height returns 0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a visible div on screen, but when I gets its height, it always returns 0. How it is possible? I have tried many jquery and javascript methods to get hight but it returns 0. This is my div:

```
<div class="option-content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="dropDownStyling" id="filterDropdowns">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Other contents -->
</div>
```

I have tried following methods to get height:

```
var $element = $("#filterDropdowns");
$element.css("height")
$element.height()
$element.innerHeight()
$element.outerHeight()
```

Also I tried javascript:

```
 document.getElementById('filterDropdowns').offsetHeight
 document.getElementById('filterDropdowns').clientHeight
```

But in all cases, it returns 0 while it returns the width value. Then why height value gets 0?

Comment: Based on html shown the element is empty and unless there is some css giving it height why wouldn't it be zero? Create a demo that replicates your problem and use enough css to represent what would affect it

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements

Comment: As I see it in the information that you have provided above, it is not clear for me if you the element's height via CSS or if the element has a content.

Comment: @charlietfl the element markup is made in javascript dynamically

Comment: Again, we can't reproduce your situation, not enough is known. All we know is with what is shown it would be zero. If there is content being added asynchronously you are probably checking the height before the html is loaded

Comment: @charlietfl The div have markup.I make markup in javasctip and then append in the element of filterdropdown.

Comment: Then create  demo that replicates your problem. We can't do that for you, we can't see the other code or css used

Comment: @Umer Is the element added to the DOM first before you tried to get it's height?

Comment: @Umer - if you have an example that replicates your issue...then what on earth would possess you to post the question with code that does NOT replicate the issue? The code you posted SHOULD read zero. We can't tell you why the other code reads zero too... **because you didn't post that code.**

Comment: I have found some links that might be of some help: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640445/get-height-of-dynamically-created-element 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913104/find-the-height-of-dynamically-created-div

Answer (score 0):

create one function & Call after DOM ready

```
    function test () {
    var height = $('#filterDropdowns').innerHeight();
alert(height)
 }


$(document).ready(function(){
$('#filterDropdowns').append('23');
test();
})

<div class="option-content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="dropDownStyling" id="filterDropdowns">

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

//Other contents
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/azL0070r/3/

Comment: hey that is so rude, why did someone down voted this answer.  Lalji Tadhani is just trying to help?

Comment: clientHeight is working using javascript not in jquery
var height = document.getElementById("filterDropdowns").clientHeight;
alert(height)

Answer (score 0):

if you use blank DIV without any content than you will always get 0 height.

For Example :

```
<div id="demo" class="text">
  <div id="abc">
  </div>
</div>
```

so you must add content in DIV

Second way to get height of DIV you can use clientHeight.

```
document.getElementById("xxx").clientHeight;
```

Comment: another way to get height isn't going to change anything

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but you're overly broad to the point of making your answer incorrect. An empty `div` will not **always** read zero height. For example if a stylesheet has a definition that gives it height that will be reflected whether that div is empty or not.

Comment: yes, if your DIV is blank but you set height using CSS than it'll also show height

Comment: Not my downvote btw...I figure your point still mostly gets across...so no need for a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="option-content">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="dropDownStyling" id="filterDropdowns">

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var height = $('#filterDropdowns').height();
alert(height)<br>
```

CSS

```
#filterDropdowns {
   height: 150px;
}
```